# Edit control and WM_CONTEXTMENU message

Tags: c, winapi

I have an Edit control which is a child of `hWnd`, the problem I am facing is that when the I right click the mouse on the Edit  control, a `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message is not sent to `hWnd` Window Procedure (while when I click on a ListView for example, a `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message is sent).

What I want to do is replace the default Edit control popupmenu with my own popupmenu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message is sent to the edit control. You are probably expecting it to be sent to the parent. That only happens when the message is passed on to `DefWindowProc`, as is the case with your list view.

From the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647592.aspx):

> If a window does not display a shortcut menu it should pass this message to the DefWindowProc function. If a window is a child window, DefWindowProc sends the message to the parent. Otherwise, DefWindowProc displays a default shortcut menu if the specified position is in the window's caption.

So, the difference between the edit control and the list view is as follows:

- The list view doesn't display a shortcut menu do it passes the message on to `DefWindowProc`. The window is a child window and so the message is sent to the parent. Where you are catching it.
- The edit control does display a shortcut menu, and so does not pass the message on to `DefWindowProc`. Which means it never gets sent to the parent, and your code does not see it.

You'll need to sub-class the edit control and listen for `WM_CONTEXTMENU` in your sub-classed window procedure.